# PHP DataBase login info in one variable

Tags: php, database, oop

I have a little code which connects to the DataBase. The login information is bothering me, because every time i want to call my login information in a function or something else I have to enter at least 3 variables. Is it somehow possible to make one variable which contains all the login information?

```
<?php
    // db login information
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mYcms";

    // db connection
    class dbconnect 
    {
        function __construct($servername, $username, $password)
        {
            if (!@$this->connect($servername, $username, $password)) {
                echo "connection failed";
            } else {
                echo "connected to " . $servername;
            }
        }
        function connect($servername, $username, $password){
            if (!mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }   
    $connection = new dbconnect($servername, $username, $password);
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't an array of details suffice?

Comment: @CharliePrynn hmm, it seems like a good idea, I don't know how but i'll figure it out I guess. thanks for your help

Comment: Why not just store your credentials in a separate file then use `require('filename.php')` to call it into the page/function whenever you need it? ALSO, you should really start using [pdo_mysql](php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). MySQL has been deprecated since PHP v. 5.5 and toally remove in version 7. Soon all of your code will stop functioning completely.

Comment: @Kuya that doesn't really solve the problem, because then i still have to call all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array:

```
$connection = array();
$connection['servername'] = "name of server";
$connection['username'] = "user";
$connection['password'] = "password";
$connection['dbname'] = "name of DB";
$connection = new dbconnect($connection);
```

in your class:

```
class dbconnect {
    // db login information
    var $connection;

    function __construct($connection){
        $this->servername = $connection['servername'];
        $this->username = $connection['username'];
        $this->password = $connection['password'];
        $this->dbname = $connection['dbname'];
        ecc...
```

I hope you helpful